# BIOS has detected unsuccessful POST attempt(s)

Tags: bios

I had the BIOS message:

> BIOS has detected unsuccessful POST attempt(s). Possible causes
>   include resent changes to BIOS Performance Options or recent hardware
>   change. Press 'Y' to enter Setup or 'N' to cancel and attempt to boot
>   with previous settings.

I know for sure there were not any hardware changes and understand that RAM or hard disk can causing the problems.

But there can be a case when nothing is wrong with hardware.

Can a sudden power off (from power board, for example) of a computer be another cause when I'm already using OS?

[image]

*PS. From my experience, to get rid of this message, it's better to press `Y` and then `F10` (to save and exit) instead of pressing `N`. If you press `N`, you may get same message again.*

Comment: Are you asking if during the POST if power was lost could it cause this error, yes it could.

Comment: No, I mean, if the above BIOS message can appear after power on after sudden power lost. I will update my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes. As mentioned above if there is a power failure *during POST*. Even if there was a power failure *after POST*, it could lead to this. Any hardware being initialized or in use could stop working and prevent subsequent POST attempts.

Comment: Yet another good reason to invest in a UPS.  They're cheap.

Comment: Can someone please edit the post? :) I don't mean power lost during startup. I mean power lost when I'm already using the OS.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, even after POST (i.e. could be in the OS), if there is a power failure, it can result in this message as well eg: a device that was in use at the time of the power failure and thus affected by it might fail to initialize and prevent successful POST attempts

Comment: I did. The bigger question is, are you able to get past this message to the OS now? If not, you should prolly post as a new question :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, this is why I haven't asked about it. From my experience, it's better to press Y and then F10 (to save and exit) instead of just pressing N ;). If you press N, you can get same message again.

Comment: I get this even when I shut down properly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After POST (i.e. could be in the OS), if there is a power failure, it can result in this message. eg: a device that was in use at the time of the power failure and thus affected by it might fail to initialize and prevent successful POST attempts.

Comment: No; pulling power while in the OS would not do this.  The power going out, coming back, then going back out again before POST completes, then coming back would.

Comment: @psusi That's interesting. Could you explain why that would cause this error to happen while just the power going out will not cause this to happen?

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  The power going out and coming back the first time causes a boot, and the power going out the second time before the POST can finish causes the error stating that POST failed ( since the power failed again before it could complete ).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error even when I'd shut down correctly. It seems like resetting the BIOS to its default settings undid whatever I messed up.